# Select priority of tasks to be performed on the UI thread in iOS

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that performs a very heavy task on one screen that runs on the UI queue. This task can be ended by switching to anything on the bottom toolbar, which is a `TabView`. However, I'm getting lag whenever I try to tap on any of the toolbar icons to end the task and switch the screen, sometimes having to push it multiple times. Is there any way that I can prioritise the screen changing on the TabView above any other tasks?

Comment: it occured whlle that task will be perform. Right?

Comment: Yes, so the task involves plotting and recording continuous high-frequency data from a Bluetooth peripheral (e.g. accelerometer data)

Comment: run that data process on `globalqueue` & run UI on `mainqueue` it might helps you alot.

Comment: The slow part is actually drawing the chart itself because the Charts library I'm using needs to repeatedly redraw the Chart data in order to simulate real-time chart updating, so although the handling of the data is already on a background queue it's not really affecting the slow part of the data plotting itself.

Comment: can show me your chart code? so i might help you.